# Issue with display click and keydown event listener result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried to set up an event listener which would listen to the user's click or keydown inputs to display the associated clip name.

```
const audioClips = [
    {
        keyCode: 81,
        keyTrigger: "Q",
        id: "Heater 1",
        src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
    },
    {
        keyCode: 67,
        keyTrigger: 'C',
        id: 'Snare',
        link: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Brk_Snr.mp3'
    }
]

function App() {

    const [displayClipName, setDisplayClipName] = React.useState('Click a key!')  

    React.useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            const keyDownUpperCase = e.key.toUpperCase()
            changeDisplay(keyDownUpperCase)
        });
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', changeDisplay)
        }
    }, [])
    
    const handleCLick = (e) => {
        const targetId = e.target.id.slice(e.target.id.length -1, e.target.id.length);
        console.log('here')
        changeDisplay(targetId)
    }

    const changeDisplay = (keyDownUpperCase, targetId) => {
        console.log(keyDownUpperCase)
        console.log(targetId)

        if (keyDownUpperCase || targetId === 'Q') {
            setDisplayClipName('You played: ' + audioClips[0].id)
        }
        else if (keyDownUpperCase || targetId === 'C') {
            setDisplayClipName('You played: ' + audioClips[8].id)
        }
        else {
            setDisplayClipName('You missed it, try again!')
        }
    }

    return (
    <div id="drum-machine" className="text-white text-center">
        <div id="display" className="container-fluid bg-info rounded p-2">
            <h1>FCC - Drum Machine</h1>
            <div onClick={handleCLick} className="pad-container bg-warning rounded p-3 m-3">
                {audioClips.map((clip) => (
                <Pad 
                    key={clip.id}
                    clip={clip}           
                />
                ))}
            </div>
            <h2>{displayClipName}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

My app looks like this but apparently, I am missing something because the third console.log(targetID) returns an empty string, and the `displayClipName` does only listen the first keydown input.

Any insights on that's wrong is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add your eventListener you only provide the the key which is pressed. You also provide an **anonymous** function which can't be used to remove the event in the useEffect cleanup.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    const keyDownUpperCase = e.key.toUpperCase();
    changeDisplay(keyDownUpperCase);
  });
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", changeDisplay);
  };
}, []);
```

To fix the issue of the eventlisteners we can just use the `changeDisplay` function as a handler.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", changeDisplay);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", changeDisplay);
  };
}, []);
```

Then in the `changeDisplay` function we need some adjustments. Your `changeDisplay` takes in **2** arguments. One for an event and another for some id. We can just transform the `key` to upper case in the function no need to do it somewhere else. The rest of the functionality can stay the same.

```js
const changeDisplay = (e, targetId) => {
  const keyDownUpperCase = e?.key?.toUpperCase();
  ...
};
```

Then there is the `handleClick` function. Which takes in a event, there is no need for that since we can simply provide the `keyTrigger` when we call the function. It can even we removed if you want to.

```js
const handleClick = (id) => {
  changeDisplay(id);
};
```

For this example I just added a `div` around the `Pad` component, if its a custom component you can add a `onClick` to the component instead of the extra div. We change the `onClick` to call `handleClick` with the first parameter of `null` since we don't have a `KeyboardEvent` and the second parameter the `clip.keyTrigger` for the `changeDisplay` to handle.

```js
<div className="pad-container bg-warning rounded p-3 m-3">
  {audioClips.map((clip) => (
    <div onClick={() => handleClick(null, clip.keyTrigger)}>
      <Pad key={clip.id} clip={clip} />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an id attribute to the div. The div with the onClick handler needs to have an `id` attribute, for example:

```
<div id="example-id" onClick={handleCLick} className="pad-container bg-warning rounded p-3 m-3">
```

`e.target.id` returns the value of the id attribute of the tag the event was triggered against.